# pagination for nested Json

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, pagination

I have a paginated API and I'm trying to go through all the data available and save it into a list. However, the nature of my API is that it's nested here's an example of how it looks like.

```
"data": [{"type": "general-Type", "id": 1, "attributes": {"firstname": "Kevin", "lastname": "Wolf", "emailaddress": "kevinwolf@gmail.com"}}]
```

Thus when I save it into a list the last part of the data aka "attributes" looks like a dictionary causing the following error:

```
    sample_data.extend(sample_data['data'])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

I'm new to this so any help on how to successfully do this request would be helpful
Thank you in advance

If it helps here's my code:
the request limit is 10,000 that's why I set the limit to 10,000 increments

```
sample_data = []
offset = 0
limit = 10000

while True:
    print("----")
    url = f"https://results.us.sampledata.com/api/reporting/v0.1.0/samples?offset={offset}&page[size]={limit}"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8", "x-apikey-token": "sampletoken"}
    print("Requesting", url)
    response = requests.get(url, data={"sample": "data"}, headers=headers)
    sample_data = response.json()

    if len(sample_data['data']) == 0:
        # If not, exit the loop
        break

    # If we did find records, add them
    # to our list and then move on to the next offset
    sample_data.extend(sample_data['data'])

    offset = offset + 10000
```

Comment: `sample_data = []` and `sample_data = response.json()`. Use different names.

Comment: That doesn't work either because the list will still see the last part of the json as a dict

Comment: The dict object is `sample_data = response.json()`.

Comment: Try to rename: `sample_data_list = []` and `sample_data_list.extend(sample_data['data'])`.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'extend'`. This means that you are trying to use a list method (extend) with an object that does not have this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @8349697 already said your problem is that you use the same name `sample_data` to keep two different structures.

First you create list `sample_data = []` but later you overwrite it with dictionary `sample_data = response.json()` but next you want to use original list `sample_data` to add values from dict `sample_data`

You should use different names like

```
page_data = response.json()

if not page_data['data']: # if len(page_data['data']) == 0:
    break

sample_data.extend(page_data['data'])
```

---

Minimal code with other changes - but I couldn't test it with your url.

```
import requests

sample_data = []

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8",
    "x-apikey-token": "sampletoken"
}

data = {
    "sample": "data"
}

params = {
    "offset": 0,
    "page[size]": 10000,
}

url = "https://results.us.sampledata.com/api/reporting/v0.1.0/samples"

while True:
    print("----")
    
    #url = f"https://results.us.sampledata.com/api/reporting/v0.1.0/samples?offset={offset}&page[size]={limit}"
    #print("Requesting", url)
    
    print('Offset:', params['offset'])

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)
    page_data = response.json()

    if (not 'data' in page_data) or (not page_data['data']): 
        break

    sample_data.extend(page_data['data'])

    params['offset'] += 10000
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the error but the loop keeps running even when I tested it with an API that I know the length it kept on running even when the api is empty. I tried your method and if len(sample_data['data']) == 0:
        # If not, exit the loop
        break 
But neither work in exiting the loop after the API is empty, any help or suggestions? thank you again!

Comment: I can't run it so I can't see what you really get in `response`. First you could use `print()` to see what you get and maybe `page_data['data']` is not empty - and maybe you need different method to recognize end of data.